# Why is the dumped marshal from c invalid when you want to load it in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, marshalling, unmarshalling, cpython

So I am modifying the cpython source code to dump each code object that gets executed. I use this code for it

```
    FILE *file;
    char yes[32] = "dumped.txt";
    
    file = fopen(yes, "a");
    PyMarshal_WriteObjectToFile((PyObject *)co, file, 1);
    fprintf(file, "SVENSKITHESOURCE");
    i++;
    fclose(file);
```

I put this code in the _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault function which gets called to run a frame.
the co variable you see here is the f->f_code object. As you can see I append it to a file called dumped.txt and later I use a script to split on this to marshal load it

```
import marshal, dis

dumps = open("dumped.txt", "rb").read()

# split the bytes file by "SVENSKITHESOURCE"
dumps = dumps.split(b"SVENSKITHESOURCE")

for dump in dumps:
    if b"Crunchy" in dump:
        print(dump)
        marshal.loads(dump)
```

I use the if to get the correct code object as I know the main code has this string.
The marshal.loads gives an error saying `ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)`. What could be the reason or how would I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure `SVENSKITHESOURCE` doesn't show up in your file for any other reasons, such as, say, appearing in the original Python source code, or already being in the file before you started writing to it (since you're opening in `a` mode)?

Comment: I would be really surprised. Would it be smarter to use a really long random string? As I don't see any other option on how to save all the code objects separately  without having 100000 files.

Comment: You're opening the file in `a` mode instead of `ab` in your C. That could be a problem.

Comment: I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks this was indeed the problem.